# Unable to split accurately

Tags: python, split, finance

I am trying to conduct some equity research. I am trying to write a code to get me some data from Yahoo Finance.

I tried this code which works fine:

```
import time
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen


bsebanks ='HDFCBANK.BO', 'ICICIBANK.BO', 'SBIN.BO'

def yahooKeyStats(stock):
    try:
        sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+stock+'/key-statistics?p='+stock+'&.tsrc=fin=srch').read()
        sourceCodeR = sourceCode.decode('utf-8')
        PB = sourceCodeR.split('Price/book</span><!-- react-text: 61 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 62 -->(mrq)<!-- /react-text --><sup aria-label="" data-reactid="63"></sup></td><td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end) Pstart(10px) Miw(60px)" data-reactid="64">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
        PE = sourceCodeR.split('Trailing P/E</span><!-- react-text: 31 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 32 --><!-- /react-text --><sup aria-label="" data-reactid="33"></sup></td><td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end) Pstart(10px) Miw(60px)" data-reactid="34">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
        print ('____________________________________')
        print (stock)
        print ('P/B',PB)
        print ('PE',PE)

    except:
        print ("NA")

for eachStock in bsebanks:
    yahooKeyStats(eachStock)
```

However, when I try the same for adding another metric, say Payout ratio, like so:

```
po = sourceCodeR.split('Payout Ratio</span><!-- react-text: 298 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 299 --><!-- /react-text --><sup aria-label="Data provided by Morningstar, Inc." data-reactid="300">4</sup></td><td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end) Pstart(10px) Miw(60px)" data-reactid="301">')[1].split('</td>')[0]

        print ('PO',po)
```

It doesn't seem to work and returns NA.

Where am I going wrong? Please help.

PS: I have not learned python. I am trying to build a stock screener for my research.

Comment: You're better off finding a data source that outputs in a more-easily machine-readable format like JSON.  If you absolutely have to scrape HTML, you should use something like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to take care of the complicated parsing for you.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the try-except block, so you the interpreter throws the error, so you can find it, and fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes to your code. You should be using a html parser for a job like this.
Here I used Beautiful Soup to solve your problem in a clean way.
Requirements: `pip install beautifulsoup4`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def yahooKeyStats(name):
    url = 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/key-statistics'.format(name)
    page = urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    pe = soup.find('span', text='Trailing P/E').find_next('td').get_text()
    pb = soup.find('span', text='Price/book').find_next('td').get_text()
    payout = soup.find('span', text='Payout ratio').find_next('td').get_text()
    print("symbol: {}\ntrailing p/e: {}\np/b: {}\npayout: {}\n".format(name, pe, pb, payout))

bsebanks = ['HDFCBANK.BO', 'ICICIBANK.BO', 'SBIN.BO']
for eachStock in bsebanks:
    yahooKeyStats(eachStock)
```

Output:

```
>> symbol: HDFCBANK.BO
>> trailing p/e: 28.37
>> p/b: 4.32
>> payout: 17.02%
>>
>> symbol: ICICIBANK.BO
>> trailing p/e: 50.00
>> p/b: 2.82
>> payout: 9.78%
>>
>> symbol: SBIN.BO
>> trailing p/e: 24.62
>> p/b: 1.26
>> payout: 0.00%
```

Comment: Perfect! Did exactly what I was looking for.